# How to time multiple commands including 'cd'?

Tags: linux, bash

Suppose I have multiple commands on one line including 'cd', for example:

```
cd subdir; pwd
```

Now I want to keep the behavior of this script the same, but time the line.

If I do this:

```
time bash -c 'cd subdir; pwd'
```

Then the behavior changes: after this line, I am no longer in `subdir`.  How to time this without interfering with the behavior of `cd`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function:

```
f() { cd subdir; pwd; }
time f
```

Comment: This doesn't work with `/usr/bin/time`: `/usr/bin/time: cannot run f: No such file or directory`